# Is there any easy way to set the default author for a node being edited to the current author if it is currently anonymous?

Tags: 7, nodes, users, forms

The site I am working on has a lot of Anonymous nodes because it is a migration from a system that didn't have a proper user system.  Users can claim their articles by going in and editing the node and changing the system author, but I'd like that to happen by default whenever someone (preferably someone who is not the administrator) edits a node that has the anonymous author.  I'm sure it must be imminently doable through some form alter or form preprocess hook, but I don't quite get the drupal form system yet.  Solutions and pointers to good sources of information both welcome.

**UPDATE** I refined this question here: [How can I set a default node owner for anonymous nodes on the node edit form?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219796/how-can-i-set-a-default-node-owner-for-anonymous-nodes-on-the-node-edit-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) function like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // If edit page is node
  if (isset($form['#node_edit_form'])) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_node_edit_submit';
  }
}


/**
 * Implements submit function for node edit.
 */
function mymodule_node_edit_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   // Get node id
   $nid = $form_state['values']['nid'];
   // Get current user
   $current_uid = $form_state['values']['uid'];
   // Load node if owner is anonymous
   if($current_uid == 0){
     // Get logged in user id to append uid as owner to node.
     global $user;
     $node = node_load($nid);
     // Set owner id as logged in user
     $node->uid = $user->uid;
     // Save node
     node_save($node);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like what you are doing there, but is there any way to do it so that the fact that the user will become the author shows in the form?  (In other words perform the alter not at the save stage, but when the form is loaded so that the user can change it if they want to)

Comment: You want user to change the author or while edit the node (before saving) you want to change node owner?

Comment: I want to set the default node owner to be the current user when the user edits a node currently owned by anonymous.  I would like the user to be able to change that if they want to (set it back to blank, or set it to a different user).

Comment: Updated answer
But if any user wants to change node owner manually, that user need permissions to "Administer content" which is not good.
Else need to write one custom field for change author and append it in save function.

Comment: I don't see the updated answer, but I use the override node options module to allow the appropriate role to be able to change the author.

Comment: Added $current_user variable to check if owner is anonymous

Comment: I see.  Thanks for that.  The thing I don't know how to do, and haven't readily been able to find a clear answer to, is the right way to set the value for this on the node edit form.  With the setup I have, I think I can do it without the node_save component.  I understand that in general it may lead to bad permission settings to do it in the way I'm trying to do it, but could you point me in the right direction for if I wanted to set the default value in the node edit form instead of on save?

Answer (score 3):

#### Option 1 - Adapt node author after editing it

If you have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module enabled, you can simply use a rule that looks like so:

```
{ "rules_change_anonymous_user_to_current_user" : {
    "LABEL" : "Change anonymous user to current user",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node-unchanged:author:uid" ], "value" : "0" } },
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } }
        }
      },
      { "NOT user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "3" : "3" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:author" ], "value" : [ "site:current-user" ] } },
      { "drupal_message" : {
          "message" : "Be aware: this was a node with an anonymous author. Since you just edited it, you are now considered as the author of it.",
          "type" : "warning"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After you enable the Rules UI, you should be able to import this rule in your own site.

Just in case it's not clear what this rule does:

- Rules Event: after updating existing content.
- Rules Conditions:

  - Author of node being edited has `uid=0`.
  - User editing the node is logged in.
  - User editing the node does NOT have role "administrator".
- Rules Actions:

  - Set node author to current user.
  - Display a (warning) message like "*Be aware: this was a node with an anonymous author. Since you just edited it, you are now considered as the author of it.*".

***Done!*** ... with Option 1.

#### Option 2 - Adapt node author after flagging it (instead of editing it)

As per your requirement like "*...whenever someone (preferably someone who is not the administrator) edits a node that has the anonymous author ...*") the previous option has a disadvantage I think: the node has to be edited. But what if the node content is actually fine, and does not need any edits at all? Therefor I'd recommend a possible alternative, which you either use together with the previous option, or as a replacement of it. Read on for more details ...

You could also use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to create a (non-global) flag that are allowed to be used by authenticated users. Let's say you define a flag labeled like "**`I am the author`**", with machine name "`i_am_the_author`". With such flag in place, you can use a variation of the rule from Option 1, which looks like so:

```
{ "rules_change_anonymous_user_to_flagging_user" : {
    "LABEL" : "Change anonymous user to flagging user",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "flag" ],
    "ON" : { "flag_flagged_i_am_the_author" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "flagged-node:author:uid" ], "value" : "0" } },
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } }
        }
      },
      { "NOT user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "3" : "3" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "flagged-node:author" ], "value" : [ "site:current-user" ] } },
      { "drupal_message" : {
          "message" : "Be aware: this was a node with an anonymous author. Since you just flagged it, you are now considered as the author of it.",
          "type" : "warning"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After you enable the Rules UI, you should be able to import this rule in your own site.

Just in case it's not clear what this rule does:

- Rules Event: after a node has been flagged, under "I am the author".
- Rules Conditions:

  - Author of node being flagged has `uid=0`.
  - User flagging the node is logged in.
  - User flagging the node does NOT have role "administrator".
- Rules Actions:

  - Set node author to current user.
  - Display a (warning) message like "*Be aware: this was a node with an anonymous author. Since you just flagged it, you are now considered as the author of it.*".

***Done!*** ... with Option 2.

#### Option 3 - Heading for the golden cradle

If you'd implement Option 2 (using the "I am the author" flag), you could even replace the rule from Option 1 by a variation of it, which is that you simply disallowed edit attempts of nodes that (still) have an anonymous user. Here is a summary of how such rule could look like:

- Rules Event : Drupal is initializing.
- Rules Condition: Current path is like `/node/nid/edit` (using a regular expression).
- Rules actions:

  - Perform a redirect (to any path that fits, eg some help page to explain the reason for the direct).
  - Set a Drupal message to indicate that edits are only allowed by a user who flagged the node first by ... you guessed it ... the "**`I am the author`**" flag.

***Voilà!***

#### Option 4 - Resolving node author disputes

No matter which solution (option) you'd use, there is always a chance that multiple users might claim to be the node author.

To also take that scenario into consideration, you could create a variation of the rule from Option 2. Some details about such rule:

- Replace 1st Rules Condition by "node author of flagged node is NOT `uid=0`.
- Replace both Rules Actions with sending an eMail to (eg) the site administrator, to indicate that some type of conflict about a node author came up (and adapt the message being shown accordingly).

***Game over!?!?***

Comment: I seem to have done a poor job of explaining what I want to accomplish because all three answers have started out helping me automatically set the author to be the current user.  I'll edit my question to make it clearer, and I apologize for the lack of clarity, but what I want is to set the default value in the node edit form.  I want the user to still have the choice of who the author is set to, but I want it to be set to them unless they explicitly choose to not have that happen.

Comment: Hey @UltraBob : changing the question after it has been answered (3 times) is not really "acceptable" on this site (since it invalidates all existing answers ...). How about instead posting a folowup question (with reference to this one if you want), and content of the new question like your prior comment?

Comment: The thing is, my original question did say that I wanted it to happen by default, which implies that there is an option to change it.  It just seems not to have been prominent enough for enough people to pick up on.  I had already saved my edit before your comment came in so please have a look at it and see if you think it is an unfair edit.  I'd be willing to make a new question if it is necessary, but I think my original question was asking what my new edit is asking.  Just in less clear fashion.

Comment: Which means, that I think if your rules solution had some way of asking the user to confirm whether they wanted to change the author when they saved, your solution would be valid even though it is not really exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: @UltraBob `I wanted it to happen by default, which implies that there is an option to change it.` There is no way anyone could've guessed that.

Comment: @UltraBob With of the PS I've added to my answer now, I leave it up to you to decide how to move forward on this. BTW, by adding a 2nd rule, I can think of a way to dispay an informational *message* whenever an authenticated user starts editing such nodes (ie that if they save such nodes, their userid will become the (new) node author ... "enforced" though (to avboid they could enter some other userid instead of their own. If that's a good, I'd be happy to expand this answer ...

Comment: @NoSssweat : I believe your comment somehow confirms my first comment here, no? Whatever it is (yes or no), because of my PS, I'm OK with my answer here (and leave it to UltraBob about how to move forward). If you can think of something to further improve my Rules based answer to answer the current version of this question, I'd be happy to read about that too (if so please add an extra answer!).

Comment: @nosssweat obviously I disagree with you on that.  A default does imply that it is changeable.  Still the evidence is on your side for how people read it, and I see that the question was not very clear which is why I changed it.  So I'll put this question back into its original state and ask a second question.  I hope you all will be kind enough to chime in there if you have an answer.  Pierre, you really seem to be a rules Maestro.  I'll get going with rules soon, but maybe not tomorrow.  Still this solution seems neat.

Comment: Hi @UltraBob (again ...) MERCI (oeps: thank you) for reconsidering your question here, and posting that followup-question. Because of that, I've removed the "PS" in my answer again also (no more need for it). About that "Maestro" in your comment: I rather consider it as "*Why make things complicated, if you can **K**eep **I**t **S**uper **S**imple*?". 1 more recommendation: hurry to get going with Rules, you don't know what you're missing ...

Comment: Sorry @UltraBob ... I just thought about "some" other "options" you may want to consider ... If I was to decide for you, I'd go for a combination of option 2, 3 and 4 ... Rules and Flag, and some config to set them up, that's all you'd need.

Comment: Pierre, your answers are always really in depth and beautiful.  If I had another upvote to give it would be forthcoming!  I think this answer is very likely to help someone else down the road.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_node_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_update().
 */
function hook_node_update($node) {
   global $user;

     //administrator role id
     $admin_rid = 3;

     //To check if user is not admin
     if (!array_key_exists( $admin_rid , $user->roles)) {
         $node->uid = $user->uid;
         node_save($node);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm trying to do it present a default value in the node edit form.  If the current owner is anonymous, set the default value for owner to be the current user, but allow the user the opportunity to change that if they want to.